# How does APNS determines a provider token's age?

Tags: jwt, apple-push-notifications

The documentation says:

> The claims payload of the token must include:
>
> - The *issued at* (iat) registered claim key, whose value indicates
>   **the time at which the token was generated**, in terms of the number of
>   seconds since Epoch, in UTC

> To ensure security, APNs requires new tokens to be generated periodically. A new token has an
> updated issued at claim key, whose value indicates the time the token was generated. If the timestamp for token issue is not **within the last hour**, APNs rejects subsequent push
> messages, returning an ExpiredProviderToken (403) error.
>
> Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html

At another section:

> *iat* | The “issued at” time, whose value indicates the time at which this JSON token was generated. Specify the value as the number of seconds since Epoch, in UTC. **The value must be no more than one hour from the current time**.

Those rules are so fragmented and repetitive at the same time, so please correct me if I'm wrong:
*iat* must be a numeric date between 1h ago and 1h from now. Let's say it's 8:30 now, and I set *iat* to 8 o'clock: does it mean my token is gonna be valid for another half hour, since that's what *iat* is telling APNS, or doest it start counting by the time APNS receive my push request? What if I set iat to 1h from now... does it mean my token is gonna be valid for 2h?

Another question. Given that:

> Refresh Your Token Regularly
>
> For security, APNs requires you to refresh your token regularly. Refresh your token no more than once every 20 minutes and no less than once every 60 minutes. APNs rejects any request whose token contains a timestamp that is more than one hour old. Similarly, APNs reports an error if you **recreate** your tokens more than once every 20 minutes.
>
> Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns

Everytime I sign a token (using a Node module for JWT), it generates a different string, even though I use the same *iat*. Does it counts as a "recreation", causing a TooManyProviderTokenUpdate error if I use it before that 20 minute threshold?